# Angular js auto nextline when paragraph or text reach certain amount of length

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Angular js auto nextline when paragraph or text reach certain amount of length. I dont want to overflow text on my design so that i why it should do next line when it reach certain count. Is there a filter to that ? or a directive?

code

```
  <a target="_self" href="{$ main.record.basic_info.linkedin_link $}"><p ><i class="fab fa-linkedin" style="display: inline" ></i> {$ main.record.basic_info.linkedin_link $}</p></a>
```

Comment: which version of angular are you using ?

Comment: Looks like what you want to achieve should be done only with CSS:
white-space: nowrap;
overflow: hidden;
text-overflow: ellipsis;

Comment: i am using angular 1

Answer (score 0):

This problem is also approachable via css using the [overflow-wrap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow-wrap)

```
overflow-wrap: break-word;
```

If you want to do it the angular way , you can create a directive which checks the length of text and injects a css class accordingly.